# How to unify three different queries in mysql when exists multiple criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table and I need to get the number of rows using different criteria. Currently I use 3 queries one after another:

1. SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1'
2. SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'10'
3. SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'20'

How do I merge these queries into a single query?

P.S. There are 30 different statuses, so GROUP BY status isn't much of an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(status), ('1') as info FROM projects WHERE project='1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(status), ('1-10') as info FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'10'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(status), ('1-20') as info FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'20'
```

Read more at:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

try using a **[Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)**

A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement.

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1'
) AS Count_1,
(
        SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'10'
) AS Count_2,
(
        SELECT COUNT(status) FROM projects WHERE project='1' AND status>'20'
) AS Count_3
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.